# How to implement SQLAlchemy Joined Table Inheritance with Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having a lot of trouble implementing Joined Table Inheritance as laid out in the SQLAlchemy documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance)!.

I am building a web app using Flask and therefore using the Flask-SQLAlchemy library. I have been able to successfully replicate the inheritance when using just SQLAlchemy. My issue arises when I start implementing it with Flask-SQLAlchemy. It seems as if Flask-SQLAlchemy makes some fundamental changes that inhibit this kind of inheritance out of the box.

To be more specific, when I query a subclass using Flask-SQLAlchemy, an InstrumentedList does indeed get returned. The problem is that it never casts to the correct subclass.

I have searched for a long time reading all the info I could possibly find but to no avail. I have tried using the with_polymorphic function from sqlalchemy but, again, to no avail.

If someone could point me in the correct direction I would greatly, greatly appreciate it. Ideally, if someone could post a minimalist, working code snippet for Joined Table Inheritance using Flask-SQLAlchemy that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Comment: hi, have you tried anything so far ? or is there any issue you re facing ?

Comment: Yes, as described above, I have tried implementing exactly as the documentation that I linked has described it. My issue is that there is not much discussion about this online. My current understanding is that the issue is with Flask-SQLAlchemy specifically and that it needs to be configured somehow. My issue at the moment is I am not sure what that entails or how to go about it. Any advice would be super helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of joined table inheritance is so neat from a database design perspective. Let us take this example below:

```
# Base class

class Employee(UserMixin, db.Model)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    type = db.Column(db.String(64))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'employee',
        'polymorphic_on': 'type'
    }

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Employee: {self.username}'



# Child1


class Manager(Employee):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    department = db.Column(db.String(64))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'manager',
        'polymorphic_load': 'inline'
    }

    def __init__(self, department):
        super().__init__(username, email, department)
        self.department = department

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Manager: {self.department}'




# Child2


class Engineer(Employee):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    stack = db.Column(db.String(64))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'engineer',
        'polymorphic_load': 'inline'
    }

    def __init__(self, stack):
        super().__init__(username, email, stack)
        self.stack = stack

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Engineer: {self.stack}'
```

There is a parent table called `Employee` that is polymorphically inherited by two children, `Manager` and `Engineer`. The base class defines common fields. The child models define fields that are specific to them.

Each model has an `identity` mapped to the discriminator column called `type`. This discriminator column typically stores strings such as in the case above, "employee", "manager" and "engineer".

To load inheritance hierarchies, polymorphic loading usually comes with an additional problem of which subclass attributes are to be queried upfront and which are to be loaded later. When an attribute of a particular subclass is queried up front, it can be used in the query as something to filter on, and it will be loaded when we get our objects back. On the other hand, if it is not queried up front, it gets loaded later when we first need to access it.

Thankfully, there are ways we can handle this problem. In the sample models shown above, I have specified that the children models should individually participate in the polymorphic loading by default using the `mapper.polymorphic_load` parameter.

If I query a particular subclass, I should be able to access all its information, which includes the data stored in the `Employee` table.

#### Updating The Models

A simple route to update a manager would look like this:

```
@app.route('/register/user/general-info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_user():
    """Registration URL"""
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['username'] = form.username.data
        session['email'] = form.email.data
        session['identity'] = form.identity.data
        session['password'] = form.password.data
        if session['identity'].lower() == 'manager':
            flash('Complete your registration as manager')
            return redirect(url_for('register_manager'))
        if session['identity'].lower() == 'engineer':
            flash('Complete your registration as engineer')
            return redirect(url_for('register_engineer'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='General User Data', form=form)



@app.route('/register/user/manager', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_manager():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = ManagerForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        manager = Manager(
            username = session['username'],
            email = session['email'],
            department = form.department.data
        )
        manager.set_password(session['password'])
        db.session.add(manager)
        db.session.commit()
        del session['username']
        del session['email']
        del session['identity']
        del session['password']
        flash(f'Registration successful. Login to continue')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register_manager.html', title='Manager Details', form=form)
```

Here, I am using two view functions, one to capture general user data, then the other for manager-specific details. In the end, I've added a manager object with all the info the `Manager` model would need.

**Querying**

In an active Python prompt, we can do the following:

```
>>> managers = Manager.query.all()
>>> for m in managers:
...     m.username, m.type, m.department

# Output
('manager_username', 'manager', 'manager_department')
```

All fields about the `manager`, including the `department` which is specific to the `Manager` model, are accessible.